# ImageViews are invisible if Viewgroups's dispatchDraw method is overwritten in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have written a custom view to display images dynamically inside a circle.

I have overwritten Viewgroup's dispatchDraw method to draw circle. After this the child ImageViews are not displaying on screen, if I do no override the method, then they are displaying on screen.

Here is my class:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

private Paint paint;
private View mView;
private Context context;


private void init(Context context) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // Set generic layout parameters
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText("Button!");
    layout.addView(button, params); // Modify this

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.coffe_selected);
    layout.addView(imageView);      

    this.addView(layout);

}

public CustomView(Context mContext) {
    super(mContext);
    context = mContext;

    // create the Paint and set its color
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(0xFF1f5b83);

    init(context);

}


@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2-64, 200, paint);
}


@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the source code of [ViewGroup](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java) and what is happening in `dispatchDraw`.

Just one line out of it:

```
more |= drawChild(canvas, transientChild, drawingTime);
```

as you can see, the childs are drawn there.
So if you don't call the super method of `dispatchDraw`, it is possible that the childs are not drawn.

**Simply call:**

```
super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
```